# Android：WebView display flash webpage ,"shouldOverrideUrlLoading" not called

Tags: android, flash, events, webview

my application uses a webView to display flash webpage. And there is a  inner button which direct other url.  I want to click the button then go to the system browser. But it doesn't work in Android 3.2 tablet.So I override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, :

```
    @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("shouldOverrideUrlLoading get the url = > " + url);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
```

But I find that : when I load the flash webpage, I click a button to open other url,the method shouldOverrideUrlLoading() will not call anyway .

And if I load the normal no flash  webpage which like "www.googel.com" , it work,the method shouldOverrideUrlLoading() will call.

And the promble get in Android 3.2 tablet.

So I think if it is the adobe flash player plus's bug??

How can I fix it ?? 
Can  you help me??

Comment: help no one know that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using actionscript 2
in you flash button you may add

```
on(press)
{
getURL("flashURL:\\www.google.com");
}
```

then in your shouldOverrideUrlLoading:

```
    @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("shouldOverrideUrlLoading get the url = > " + url);
                url = url.substring(url.indexOf("flashURL:\\") + 1)
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
```

apparently you have to create a custom protocol (e.g "flashURL:\", "gameURL:\" etc..) in order for shouldOverrideUrlLoading to trigger in 3.2